# Is it possible to add fields not described in Mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example I have schema like this:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url:  String,
    unique: {type: String, index: { unique: true }},
    number: String,
    title: String,
    price: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
```

When I'm creating new instance is it possible to add extra fields without describing them in the model? For example:

```
data.bpm = {foo: 'bar'}

new CarModel(data).save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        dd(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `strict: false` option.

[Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict):

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

Your updated schema will look like this:

```
let carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url:  String,
    unique: {type: String, index: { unique: true }},
    number: String,
    title: String,
    price: String,
}, { strict: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use type 'Schema.Types.Mixed' for some field in your schema:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

let carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    url:  String,
    ...
    data: Schema.Types.Mixed
});
```

And then use .data field as js object.

Answer (score -1):

You can not since mongoose schema will check if that attribute exists or not, but what you can do is, you can add the following attribute to carSchema:

`externalData: Object`

And you can set that data to be anything you want.